# Monotone function with the properties below

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Does there exist any strictly decreasing function $f: \Bbb R \to [0,+\infty)$ such that $f(x)-\sqrt{f(x)}$ is strictly increasing function on the whole $\Bbb R$?

Now, we had calculus at high school, but, at the moment, we haven't gone through it in analysis lectures, so, on the first exam we are supposed to use things mentioned in lectures only.
I tried to use the fact that if $f(x)$ is a monotonically decreasing function, then the composition $$f(f(x))$$ is monotonically increasing. I might have chosen the wrong path. I also considered inverses, but it didn't help me either.
Since I have a sum, I assumed, without deriving, I can't look at it as a real composition.
$$\operatorname{Ran}(f)=[0,+\infty)$$ implies $\sqrt{f(x)}$ would be defined well.
I constantly kept returning to some decreasing exponential function $g(x)=a^{x}, a\in(0,1)$ although a rational function with odd exponents seemed equally useful/useless...
I thought that the degree of $f(x)$ must be less than the degree of  $\sqrt{f(x)}$ in terms of that exponential function. I haven't proven it.
The role of the leading coefficient also seemed irrelevant in this case, it reminded me of polynomials, but they can't be injective and always positive at the same time globally, without restriction, am I right?
I "concluded" there is no such function that satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Write $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ and differentiate $g(x)^2 - g(x)$.

Comment: With the help of calculus, one finds that this is so if $f(x) < \frac 14$ for all $x$, which is of course possible.

Comment: But since you had it in school, you can informally differentiate to find the condition(s). When you have the condition, you can manipulate things (considering $h(y) - h(x)$ for $y > x$, where $h(x) = g(x)^2 - g(x)$) to show it without using the derivative.

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.

Comment: Remember, it is irrelevant in which way you _find_ a solution, but to _write up_ a solution, you can only use things you officially know (or explicitly prove).

Comment: Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $h$ be any decreasing function with $0 < h < \frac 12$. Then
>   $g:=h^2-h$ is increasing.

*Proof*. Let $a>0$. We have to show that $g(x+a) > g(x)$ for each $x$. This is equivalent to
$$
h(x)-h(x+a) > h(x)^2-h(x+a)^2 = (h(x)-h(x+a))(h(x)+h(x+a)).
$$
Since $h(x)-h(x+a) > 0$, we may divide and obtain the equivalent inequality
$$
h(x)+h(x+a) < 1,
$$
which is true by assumption.

---

In your case, set $h = \sqrt f$. So, whenever $f(x) < \frac 14$ for all $x$, this is a function as desired.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit different, maybe more elementary approach.

If $f:\Bbb R\to[0,+\infty)$ is strictly decreasing, then for any $x_1,x_2\in\Bbb R:$
$$x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)\implies\sqrt{f(x_1)}<\sqrt{f(x_2)}\space.$$

Let $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$ and let $h(x)=f(x)-\sqrt{f(x)}=g(x)^2-g(x),$ so $$\begin{aligned}h(x_1)&=g(x_1)^2-g(x_1)\\h(x_2)&=g(x_2)^2-g(x_2)\space.\end{aligned}$$

We see that $g$ is decreasing and, by the assumption, $h$ is increasing. Therefore $$\begin{aligned}h(x_2)-h(x_1)&=g(x_2)^2-g(x_2)-g(x_1)^2+g(x_1)\\&=(g(x_2)-g(x_1))(g(x_2)+g(x_1)-1)\\&=\underbrace{(g(x_1)-g(x_2))}_{>0}(1-(g(x_1)+g(x_2)))>0\\\\\implies1-(g(x_1)+g(x_2))&>0\\\iff 1>g(x_1)+g(x_2)&>2g(x_2)\\\iff g(x_2)=\sqrt{f(x_2)}&<\frac12=\sqrt{\frac14}\\\iff f(x_2)<\frac14\end{aligned}$$
Since $x_1,x_2$ were arbitrary, $f(x)<\frac14\space\forall x\in\Bbb R.$